# Applescript how to open network window of Audio MIDI Setup

Tags: networking, macos, automation, applescript

I'm trying to write an Applescript to create a network audio connection using the **Audio MIDI Setup** (*/Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup.app*). I'm not able to open the *Network Setup* window.  There seems to be an image that I have to perform a click on in order to open the Network Window.

This is what i have tried:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Audio MIDI Setup"
            set {xPos, yPos} to position of image 1 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of window "MIDI Studio"
        end tell
    end tell

    tell me to do shell script "/usr/bin/cliclick c:" & xPos & "," & yPos
    click at {xPos, yPos} --image "Network" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of window "MIDI Studio"
    delay 0.1
    --click image "Network" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of window "MIDI Studio"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the image you mentioned has an AppleScript action associated with it that is supposed to open the *MIDI Network Setup* window, but in reality, it does nothing.

Therefore, as a workaround, to open the *MIDI Network Setup* window, try this:

```
    tell application "Audio MIDI Setup" to activate

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Audio MIDI Setup" 
        (******************Variable declarations for GUI objects*******************)
        set _W to a reference to (every window whose ¬
            description contains "floating window" and ¬
            name is not "MIDI Network Setup")
        set select_all_menu_item to ¬
            a reference to menu item "Select All" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu bar item "Edit" of ¬
                menu bar 1
        set show_midi_studio_menu_item to ¬
            a reference to menu item "Show MIDI Studio" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu bar item "Window" of ¬
                menu bar 1
        set midi_studio_window to a reference to window "MIDI Studio"
        set midi_studio_toolbar to a reference to toolbar 1 of midi_studio_window
        set midi_studio_images to a reference to images of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            midi_studio_window
        set show_info_button to a reference to (the first button of ¬
            midi_studio_toolbar whose description is "Show Info")
        (**********************End of variable declarations************************)

        if not (midi_studio_window exists) then click show_midi_studio_menu_item
        tell midi_studio_window to perform action "AXRaise" -- bring window to front

        if the front window is midi_studio_window then
            tell select_all_menu_item to if it exists then click it
            --OR: keystroke "a" using command down

            if the show_info_button is enabled then
                click the show_info_button
                click (every button of _W whose subrole is "AXCloseButton")

                tell window "MIDI Network Setup" to perform action "AXRaise"
            end if
        end if
    end tell
```

If you have any problems with this, leave a comment and I'll get back to you.  Otherwise, consider selecting this answer to help guide other users to it should they be experiencing similar issues.

Comment: Firstly, don’t leave comments as answers.  Also, write your comments against my answer if they relate to it, as yours did.  I only came back here by chance, otherwise I would have had no idea you tried to respond.  What version of MacOS and AppleScript are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I  can't get your script to work, it do not open the "MIDI Network Setup" window, and i had to change "description" to "title" in the following line
set show_info_button to a reference to (the first button of ¬
        midi_studio_toolbar whose description is "Show Info")

Answer (score 0):

This script is doing the job
tell application "Audio MIDI Setup" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Audio MIDI Setup"
        tell menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1

```
        if name is "Show MIDI Studio" then click

    end tell
end tell
tell process "Audio MIDI Setup"
    set {xPos, yPos} to position of image "Network (Online)" of group 1 of  scroll area 1 of window "MIDI Studio"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  dc:" & xPos & "," & yPos & ""
end tell
```

end tell
tell application "Audio MIDI Setup" to quit